# CSS selector for next siblings until certain other selector

Tags: css

Given a *flat* list of elements (must be flat), I would like to a find an ideal combination of CSS selectors which colors **only** the `<a>` elements which comes after a *checked* `<input>`(checkbox), but **not** those who comes after some next sibling input:

(The number of items per checkbox is dynamic)

#### Is there a way to refactor the CSS selectors?

I've tried combinations with `:has` or `:is` but cannot come up with the right combination.

Ideally I would like a single selector for coloring on the `<a>` items between the checked input and the input the comes after it in the DOM tree.

#### There is also a bug in the below situation (see row 4):

*(It's quite a pickle...)*

[image]

```css
* {
  float: left;
  user-select: none;
}

input {
  clear: left;
}

input:checked ~ a,
input:checked ~ a ~ input:not(:checked) ~ :checked ~ a{
  background: gold;
}

input:checked ~ a ~ input:not(:checked) ~ a {
  background: none;
}
```

```html
<input type=checkbox checked>
<a></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>

<input type=checkbox>
<a></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>

<input type=checkbox checked>
<a></a>

<input type=checkbox>
<a></a>
<a></a>
```

---

I've created a [proposal for an `:until` pseudo-selector](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/8815)

Comment: I don't understand what you want exactly

Comment: @XMehdi01 - you see the bug? I want only the next `<a>` siblings of a checked input to be colored, and **not** others which come after other inputs. (run the snippet and see the problem)

Answer (score 0):

## Complex CSS Solution

This solution involves `position`, pseudo-elements, and `:has()`. This solution will work for an unknown number of `<a>`s and lines that pre-existed or dynamically added (see **Example A**).

### Example A

### **Details are commented in example**

```css
* {
  float: left;
  user-select: none;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

input {
  clear: left;
}

a {
  position: relative /* Allows ::after to reference <a> for
  positioning and stacking order */;
}

/*
- Targets the last <a> of each line.
- It's purpose is to mask any gold background that extends past 
  the last <a> of each line.
- Content is "" which is transparent and is used to mirror
  the dimensions of a <a>.
- Pseudo-element is positioned to the outside right edge of the
  last <a> of each line.
*/
a:has(+input)::after, 
a:last-of-type::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 100%;
  width: 96vw;
  color: transparent;
  background: white;
}

/*
- Targets the first <a> of each line.
- It's purpose is to add a gold background that extends close
  to the right edge of viewport for each line that's checked.
- Content is "" which is transparent and is used to mirror
  the dimensions of a <a>.
- Pseudo-element is positioned to the inside left edge of the 
  first <a> of each line. 
*/
input:checked+a::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -2;
  left: 0;
  width: 96vw;
  color: transparent;
  background: gold;
}

/*
Same as previous but width is adjusted for lines with a single
<a>.
*/
input:checked+a:has(+input)::after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" checked><a></a><a></a><a></a>
<input type="checkbox"><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a>
<input type="checkbox" checked><a></a>
<input type="checkbox"><a></a><a></a>
<input type="checkbox" checked><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a>
<input type="checkbox"><a></a><a></a><a></a><a></a>
<input type="checkbox" checked><a></a>
<input type="checkbox"><a></a><a></a>
```

## Simple HTML Solution

If you're looking for the most simplest of selectors, you'll need to isolate each group in the layout with HTML. Wrap each group in a `<label>` and assign `clear: left` to each `label`. The last ruleset isn't needed (see **Example B**).

### Example B

### ```css
* {
  float: left;
  user-select: none;
}

label {
  clear: left;
}

input:checked~a {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<label>
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
</label>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
</label>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <a></a>
</label>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox">
  <a></a>
  <a></a>
</label>
```

Comment: As I've mentioned in the question *"Given a flat list of elements"*. That is what you have to work with. The question is CSS-only (as also tagged)

Comment: Just because those are your requirements doesn't mean that it's possible to satisfy those requirements with current CSS.

Comment: If it is not then it is best to leave it unanswered until one day it will be possible. I am sure it is possible, just need to be clever about this. There is a trick, I feel i'm close to solving it.

Comment: Hi @vsync I figured as much but I wanted to post the obvious solution for the novice. If I come up with another solution I'll add it.

Comment: Looks like you're right @vsync it is possible, see updated answer.

Comment: It's not really about coloring a simple `<a>`, as it is only a highly-simplified example. The range of real-world use-cases are far outreaching, as those `<a>` elements can be any complex components with lots of styles being applied to it, when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: Did you even try testing it yet? Edit your question with specific examples not generalities. If your concern is about real world cases, perhaps you should post code involving `classNames`, also more common HTML layouts have tons of tags nested within each other, and `<label>`s are also a common occurrence wherever `<input>`s are used.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I can actually see is a "pyramid" selector using `+` until the max number of elements you know you will have.

```css
* {
  float: left;
  user-select: none;
}

input {
  clear: left;
}

input:checked + a,
input:checked + a + a,
input:checked + a + a + a,
input:checked + a + a + a + a,
input:checked + a + a + a + a + a,
input:checked + a + a + a + a + a + a,
input:checked + a + a + a + a + a + a + a {
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<input type=checkbox checked>
<a></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>

<input type=checkbox>
<a></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>

<input type=checkbox checked>
<a></a>

<input type=checkbox>
<a></a>
<a></a>
```

Comment: Yes, I was thinking the same, but it's so ugly.. CSS is so limited in the sense that there is selector for `until`. If there an `until` selector... a game changer: `:checked ~ a:until(input)`

Comment: @vsync it's not limited, we can simulate the until between two instances (https://css-tip.com/select-elements-between-two-class/) but if you say :until(input) then the question is which one of the inputs? it may look trivial but it's not.

Comment: until the first one encounters in the DOM tree, going forward from the the main selector's (`a`) siblings, so literally "all anchor tags which comes after an input which is checked, but until first selector encountered, which is an `input` selector in my case." So, all `a` are selected up to the first `input` found, then none afterwards.

Comment: the mentioned CSS tip above is for a very narrow use-case. Not applicable here as you know. Just a trick for simple situations where the HTML is structured in an easy-to-work-with manner

Comment: @vsync you can always propose this selector to the Working Group if you think it's something worth adding and can be easy to implement.

Comment: Yes, I constantly [hang out here](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts)

Comment: I've [created a proposal](https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/8815). I hope it is written in a clear way, because there is really no easy way as-of-today with the use-case i've outlined there